# Creating a array of objects using a constructor

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to have an People array containing Person objects so that I can access the fields in the object from the array index.

Normally I'd have gone with and object collection or List etc.

Can you help me make this work?...

```
var people = [];

var person = {
    firstName:"John",
    age:50
  };



function newPerson(){       
    var p = new person();   //<<< #1. Is this a good approach in JS?
    p.firstName = "Fred";
    p.age = 21;

    people.push(p);
}


function totalAge(){

    var totalAge =0; 
    for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
        totalAge += people[i].age;   //<<<<< #2. This is the kind of access I want.
    }
}
```

Comment: Constructors need to be **functions**, not objects. Your "person" variable is initialized to a plain object, so you can't call it as a constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, [JsBin sourses](http://jsbin.com/jogegifi/2/)

```
    var people = [];

    function Person(name, age){  // Function constructor
      this.name = name;          // do not forget 'this.'
      this.age = age;
    }

    function addPerson(name,age){    
        var p = new Person(name,age); // here we create instance
        people.push(p);
    }

    addPerson("Petia", 80);
    addPerson("Vasia", 20);


    function totalAge(){
        var total = 0;      // do not name local variables same as function
        var i;             // use var for i variable, otherwise it would be global variable 
        for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
            total += people[i].age; 
        }
        return total;
    }

    var total = totalAge();
    console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 1):

Little more objective

```
function People() {
    this.people = [];
}

People.prototype.getTotalAge = function() {
   return this.people.reduce(function(totalAge, person) {
        return totalAge + person.age;
    }, 0); 
};

People.prototype.add = function() {
    var people = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    this.people = this.people.concat(people);
};

//Person function behave as a class by this you can make new instance
function Person(fname, age) {
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.age = age;
}

var people = new People();
var p1 = new Person("fred", 21);
var p2 = new Person("John", 24);
people.add(p1, p2);

alert(people.getTotalAge());
```

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/Zkc43/3/ – thanks to @Akhlesh

Answer (score 1):

here is another approach using prototypes.
Classes (like in Java) are a fairly foreign concept to JavaScript, so i'd recommend not to try emulating them.

```
(function(){

    var people, Person, totalAge;

    // a Person prototype
    Person = Object.create({});

    // factory method creating Person objects
    Person.create = function Person_create (firstName, age) {

        var p = Object.create(Person);

        p._firstName = firstName;
        p._age = age;

        return p;

    };

    // getter for _age
    Person.getAge = function Person_getAge () {

        return this._age;

    };

    // generate some test values
    function populate (max) {

        var result, i;

        result = [];
        i = 0;

        while (i < max) {

            result.push(Person.create("Person"+i,i));
            i++;

        }


        return result;

    }

    // array containing test objects
    people = populate(100);

    // compute the sum of all Person.age
    totalAge = people.reduce(function(age,p){

        return age + p.getAge();

    }, 0); // <- 0 as initial value, basically you choose the neutral element for the operation in the given group (for multiplication initial value would be 1)

    console.log(totalAge);

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this,

```
 var people = [];

function newPerson(){

    people.push({"firstName":"Fred", "age":21});
}


function totalAge(){

    var totalAge =0; 
    for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++){
          totalAge += people[i].age;   //<<<<< #2. This is the kind of access I want.
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new`, but you will have to use it with a constructor function (any function could be used as a constructor). The `new` operator cannot be applied to an object literal.

```
function Person(firstName, age) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.age = age;
}

var p = new Person('Fred', 21);

p.age; //21
```

If you want to use an object as a prototype for another object you can use `Object.create`.

```
var basePerson = { name: 'Default', age: 0 },
    p = Object.create(basePerson);

p.age; //0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use constructor function for creating object like:-

```
 var people = [];
 //Person function behave as a class by this you can make new instance
 function Person(fname, age) {
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.age = age;
 }

 var p1 = new Person("fred", 21);
 var p2 = new Person("Jhon", 24);
 people.push(p1, p2);


 function totalAge() {

   var totalAge = 0;
   for (i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
      totalAge += people[i].age; //<<<<< #2. This is the kind of access I want.
   }
   return totalAge;
 }
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zkc43/)

Answer (score 0):

**Class in JS**

```
var Person = function(firstName, age) {
    this.firstName = '';
    this.age = '';
    this.createNewPerson=function(firstName, age) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.age = age
    }
    this.createNewPerson(firstName, age)
}

var people = [];
var newPerson = new Person('harp',23);
people.push(newPerson)
```

Comment: Hi. Why did you use "this.createNewPerson"?  (and thanks btw)

Comment: just an example function. I thought it would help you better understand. actually I used it as a constructor.

Comment: If every thing is clear(I hope), then you can accept any answer you liked most.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:-

```
       function test(){
            var person = new Person('Jhon',10),
            person2 = new Person('Jhons',20),
            persons = [],total =0 ;
            persons.push(person);
            persons.push(person2);

            for(var i=0; i<persons.length; i++){
                total += persons[i].age;
            }
            console.log(persons,total);
        }
        function Person(name,age) {  
            this.name = name;
            this.age =age;
            return this;
        }
```